# How to draw random samples from this distribution $f(x)=2xe^{x^2}$ of size hundred

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

How to draw random samples from this distribution $f(x)=2xe^{x^2}$ of size hundred?
Please explain I am a beginner

Comment: Do you mean $2xe^{-x^2}$? And are you able to draw samples from a uniform $U(0,1)$ distribution?

Comment: How should i draw

Answer (score 1):

I am unclear on exactly what you are asking, but I think you are looking for an [Inverse Transform Sampling](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling). The basic idea is that you integrate your function, find its inverse, generate a random number in the range, and put it into the function.